# generateJWT is not a function

Tags: node.js, facebook, json-web-token

i'm trying to make facebook login possible:

This is my API route:

```
router.post('/registerFb', function(req, res, next){
  User.find({ 'username': req.body.username}, function(err, foundUser){
    if(err)
      return next(err);

    var co = Object.keys(foundUser).length;

    if (co === 0)
    {
      var user = new User();

      user.username = req.body.username;
      user.firstname = "firstname";
      user.lastname = "lastname";
      user.difficulty = "easy";
      user.isstudent = false;
      user.haschildren = false;
      user.gender = "male";
      user.isdoingchallenges =  false;
      user.facebookid = req.body.facebookid;

      user.save(function (err){
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
      });
    }else{
      return res.json({token: foundUser.generateJWT()});
    }
  });
});
```

When its the first time that a user logs in with facebook, the user is stored and a token is generated with jsonwebtoken.

However when there is already a user from that fb account, it gives me the error:

> TypeError: foundUser.generateJWT is not a function

Why is this happening? generateJWT on a new user works but not on a found user?

I edited my API route to this:

```
if (co === 0)
    {
      var user = new User();

      user.username = req.body.username;
      user.firstname = "firstname";
      user.lastname = "lastname";
      user.difficulty = "easy";
      user.isstudent = false;
      user.haschildren = false;
      user.gender = "male";
      user.isdoingchallenges =  false;
      user.facebookid = req.body.facebookid;

      user.save(function (err){
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
      });
    }else{
      var user = new User();
      user._id = foundUser._id;
      user.username = foundUser.username;
      return res.json({token: user.generateJWT()});
    }
```

When used in postman, it returns a token like expected.

But when I use it in production mode, I get a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` is an instance of `User` while `foundUser` is an object returned by `User.find` method.

You probably need to modify `find` method to return instance of `User` or in case it's a db (mongo?) handler create an instance of `User` in a callback prior to calling `generateJWT` method.

Comment: @stijn26, you need to create instance of `User` which represent the data in `foundUser`

Comment: Ok edited and it works in postman now, however in production mode I get a 500 internal server error